# Show Results Based on Series of Radio Button Questions?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've tried searching but not sure where to start. I'm not expecting an answer but was hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I'm trying to show results based on a series of questions.

**Q. What is your operating system?**

- Option 1. Apple
- Option 2. Window

**Q. What is your screen size?**

- Option 1. 11-inch
- Option 2. 13-inch
- Option 3. 15-inch

**Q. What color case are you looking for?**

- Option 1. Blue
- Option 2. Green
- Option 3. Red

If I select Option 1 for all it should display all Blue cases that are compatible with a 11" Apple device.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of what to search for? What is this process called? Sorry if this isn't the appropriate place for this question but I'm having a hard time getting started.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `Cascading drop down` or `Dynamic drop down` are what I know it as. Search those plus the technology you want to implement it in ie `Cascading drop down php` or `dynamic drop down jquery`.

Comment: @cOle2 perfect, thanks!